# How to determine needed amount of random samples of whole population?

Tags: sample-size, population, neuroscience

I wrote an algorithm that categorizes a large set of electrophysiological data, way more than I could go through per hand (think over 10.000 cells).

I want to take randomly drawn sample cells out of this population, categorize them manually and control if the algorithm works correctly. Is there any test that determines the amount of randomly drawn samples I'd have to review manually, so I could say the algorithm works statistically significant on the whole population?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us how you classify cells - how many classes of cells are there - and whether you are looking to check classification of individual cells or if you are just interested on proportion of cells.

However, the size of the sample is related to the power of the test. That is, if you take a large sample you'll be able to check if there is a small difference between manual and automatic classification; if you take an small sample, you are unlikely to notice any difference unless it's rather large.

As I said, we can't give good answers without knowing your goals, but if you are just interested on the percentage of misclassified cells, you are just estimating a proportion from a sample, and you can find information on confidence intervals or and power of the proportion test.

As a rough idea, assuming the worst case, the precision of a proportion test is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ with confidence level 95%. That is, if with a 10 observations sample you'll be able to find misclassification with $\pm30\%$ (at worst), with a 100 items sample $\pm10\%$. However, this is a rough approximation in the worst case and if misclassification error is small precision of its estimation can improve.